# list-style-type is not working in IE 7 when i am using float inside li

Tags: html, css, list, css-float

I am using `list-style-type:disc` inside `<ul>` , but when  i am using `float:left` to `<li>` tag, after that bullets are not displaying in ie7, its working in all other browsers.

### HTML

```
<ul class="more-about-details">
<li><a href="#">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#">two</a></li>                
<li><a href="#">Three</a></li>                  
<li><a href="#">four</a></li>
<li><a href="#">five</a></li>
<li><a href="#">six</a></li>                
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
body {
    line-height:1;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
ul.more-about-details {
    width: 97%; 
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 3%; 
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    float: left;
}
.more-about-details li {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px 3.28% 0px 0px; 
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.more-about-details li a{
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-type: disc;
    display: list-item;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me why its not working with <li>  ?